# What is wrong with my equation or conversions?

Tags: c++, physics, trigonometry, equation

> R (in feet) = (velocity (in ft/s))^2 / g (which is 9.8 m/s^2) * sin(2theta).

I checked various inputs using websites like this one https://www.ajdesigner.com/phpprojectilemotion/range_equation.php#ajscroll to check if my code was giving the right answer but it isn't and I don't know why. Any simple solutions?? Here it is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double GRAVITY_MPS = 9.8;
const double METERS = 3.28084;


int main() {

    double v = 0.0, degrees = 0.0;

    cout << "Enter the velocity (mi/hr) and cannon angle (degrees): \n";
    cin >> v >> degrees;

    double v2 = 0.0;
    v2 = v * 5280.0 / 3600.0;

    double radians = degrees * M_PI / 180.0;

    double r = (pow(v2,2.0) / GRAVITY_MPS) * sin((2.0 * radians));

    double r2 = r * METERS;

    cout << "Yikes travels " << r2 << " feet.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're mixing feet and meters.  Also, what is the magic number 3.2808398950131?

Comment: Found it on a website to be more accurate of a conversion. I updated it now.

Comment: As @dbush said, what is `3.2808398950131` make sure to make it a constant variable.

Comment: That is okay to have that number but you want to make sure you are creating a variable for it. It is easier to maintain and has better readability.

Comment: its the exact value of pi (using the math library cmath)

Comment: @userh16xx0 instead of that you should create a const pi variable it will be more portable.

Comment: If I saw `METERS = 3.28084` in code it would take a while for me to figure out what it meant. Almost worse than directly using 3.28084 later in the code. I would write something like `FEET_PER_METER = 3.28084`. Or better still, `const double FEET_PER_METER = 1/0.3048` since that will give you the correct value accurate to the limit of precision of a double.

Comment: Why work in double precision when you have such an approximate value for *g*? You'll be out on the inches with that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your v0 can't be in feet cause gravity is in meters.
Change `5280.0` to `1609.3` (mi to m) and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: This gives an answer in meters, not feet.

Comment: The rest of his code accounts (r2 part)

Answer (score 4):

The value of `r` has units (ft/s)<sup>2</sup> / (m/s<sup>2</sup>) == (ft<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>) / (m/s<sup>2</sup>) == ft<sup>2</sup> / m.  Then `r2` has units ft<sup>2</sup>/m * ft/m resulting in units of ft<sup>3</sup> / m<sup>2</sup>.

You want the inverse of the multiplication factor for `r2`, i.e. m/ft:

```
double r2 = r * 0.3048;   // meters / foot
```

Comment: To convert r meters to feet you want something like `(r meters)*(3.28084 feet/meter)`. Obviously that's not actual code, but it's meant to show how units conversions work: the meters cancel out (meters/meter = 1) and you're left with feet. Personally I would use 1/0.3048 as the constant (since that's the exact definition) rather than copying some digits of an approximation from some website, but the end result is the feet should be more than 3 times larger than the number of meters, not the other way around.

Comment: @DavidK That's what OP had originally which didn't work because they needed to go the other way.  They had ft^2/meter so they needed meter/ft to get feet.

Comment: I think I see now, you're trying to fix the program by just adjusting the one conversion factor at the end. But (as you point out) this leaves the distance `r` measured in units of ft^2/m, which IMHO is simply insane. If I were reviewing software that did this I wold send it back for rework. Choose standard units and use them consistently. The accepted answer actually fixes the error of mixed ft and meters in the main formula for distance. That's a much better solution.